# Wireframe shader with gradient colors

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I am trying to land a project similar to the one in this image. Any ideas how I could get a similar render for any type of figure, for example a Torus or an octagon? I don't care about the mesh, but about the render type (wireframe, colors, and maybe shader).

I don't really know what could help to nail this. Maybe by using some kind of freestyle set? All ideas are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please use a descriptive title that sumarizes the content of the question. Also clarify what part of the image you wish to recreate. Is it the modelling, the shading, colors, wireframes?

Comment: Ill edit it. Thanks for the feedback. I´d like to recreate the shading and the wireframe, so i can use it in any shape. Setting colors like this may also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a try:

- Create your profile shape (here an extruded triangle) and a curve, give your shape an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier so that it follows the curve, then a *Wireframe* modifier so that it thickens the edges. Disable the *Replace Original* option of the *Wireframe* modifier so that you can still see the original faces.

[image]

- Create 2 materials, one for the faces, one for the edges. The first material is a mix between a *Transparent* shader and an *Emission* shader, with a *Layer Weight* as factor.

[image]

- The second material is a basically a mix between *Emission* shaders and a *Transparent* shader, with a *Noise* shaders as factors, in order to create a blend of colors and transparency.

[image]

- In the material list of your object (*Material* panel), put the first material (faces material) above the second one (edges material). In the Wireframe modifier, choose *Material Offset* > 1 so that the edges will have the second material of your material list.

[image]

- Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: I´ll try it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just create a cylinder and decrease vertice
[image]

and scale it and add same loop cuts and add a curve
 and towic it until it is mash the reference and 
 curve modifier to follow the curve and wireframe modifier
and finally add the gradient texture with the mapping node and texture coordinate
  and use it as a mask to  in the mix shader by connect it to the fac 
and but the two emission shader with different colors to it

Comment: Periods, commas, and sentence structure, might make this answer more useful.